# Java: Adding items to two seperate list in a recursive function

Tags: java, list, recursion

I am trying to add items to two seperate lists in a recursive method. As I need the outcome to be two separate lists (or perhaps a map).

I want the output to be two lists where the input of all the tasks that need to be assigned are listed based on cheapest cost. So:

```
Set {task1, task2, task3, task 4, etc.}
A: [task2, task3]
B: [task1, task4]
```

The code looks like this:

```
public Assignments {

    Set<Task> unassignedTasks = new HashSet<>();
    List<Task> assignment = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Task> firstTasks = [task0, task00] //a list with the task that is already being performed for two assignees


    public Assignment assign(Task task1, Assignments sched){
    //fields to store some attributes of task1

        /* recursive function */ 
        for(Task task2: unassignedTasks){
            // fields to store some attributes of task2 
            if(task2 fits after task1){
                // calculate cost of performing task2 at this point in time
                double cost = task1.getCost() + assign(task2, sched));
                if(cost < value){
                assignment.add(task1);
                }
            } else if(!firstTasks.isEmpty()){
              // here I'd like it to skip to the second list
                firstTasks.remove(0);
                Task nextCurrentTask = firstTasks.get(0);
                cost = cost + assign(nextCurrentTask, sched);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Obviously, this approach leads to an output of one list.
My question is then how can I ensure that whenever the algorithm ends up in the else-if block that it iterates to a second list and constructs this list?

I thought of having a list of lists `List<List<Object>>,` but then I have the problem of adding the initial list to the list of lists at the right time. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but the question is still a bit unclear for me. I tried reading it twice but lost it both the times while reading the last paragraph. Could you try adding more details and examples of what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: on what basis are you assigning the tasks to each list ?

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand the question, but have you tried passing a parameter to the recursive function that tells it which list to add to?

Comment: Alright, I'll try to be clearer. As input I have a set that contains unassigned tasks, two assignees and two tasks that are already being performed by the two assignees. My goal is to give both the assignees the follow up on that task that is being performed. 

Therefore, as output I with to have two lists (or a map) that contains this information. However, the algorithm as I wrote it adds all the tasks to one list to which it becomes difficult to find out which items belong to which assignee. I am trying to come up with a way where the outcome is separate and I know which task belongs to whom

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh I am assigning the tasks based on whether one can be actually scheduled after another and on cost. I want the cheapest assignments.

Comment: @user2455627 I thought of passing an object that contains both lists, but and I believe that is what I am trying to do here, but I do not know yet how I can tell the recursive function to which list to add it to.

Comment: @k88 I'm assuming you know what conditions put an object in list 1 or list 2, and that you would be able to determine this in your code. What I am suggesting is add an int parameter then when you add to a list you check which list to put it in then put it in the proper one. If you only have two lists a boolean would work as well

Comment: so u mean u want to sort the tasks based on cost and then assign them to the 2 assignes in a fashion that they dont overlap ?

Comment: @RenukaDeshmukh Exactly. Basically, I try to do a search of all possible combination and then select the cheapest option so that they do not overlap and, preferably,  all of them are assigned

Comment: @user2455627 I didn't think of that yet. I'll try to implement that and report back.